# Why would one check whether file permissions ANDed with 0007 are true?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I stumbled upon this construction:

```
((($(stat -c '0%#a' "$FILE_PATH") & $(stat -c '0%#a' "${FILE_PATH%/*}") & 0007) == 0))
```

I understand that first parenthesis part returns file permission bits in octal, and second path returns file's folder (everything in Linux is a file) permissions. But what is the last bitwise operation for? Is it check for some vulnerability?

I see that first `stat -c "0%#a" file` returns 00640 and `stat -c "0%#a" file_path` returns 00640, with 0007 the whole expression 00640 & 00640 & 0007 = 0, but what does it mean concerning to Linux file permissions?

Comment: Remember, it's user/group/other, so that last 7 is the "other".

Comment: BTW, _usually_ "explain this code" questions are considered categorically overbroad and thus off-topic. It's unusual to see something like this that's arguably a good one.

Comment: Another aside: There's a bug here; it would be safer if the check used a `|` to combine the `stat` results, and then a `&` to check the result of that merge. There are unsafe permissions that could get through the check as currently written (you don't want users to have write to a directory that contains a file they're not supposed to have write to; the write permissions on the directory can be used to circumvent the lack of write permissions on the file).

Comment: Which is to say, ideally, you'd want `$(( ( 00640 | 00640 ) & 07 ))`

Comment: So, `$(( ( 00640 | 00640 ) & 07 )) = ( 110100000 | 110100000 ) & 000000111 = 0` and it means that only owner and owner's group can read, write and execute file or folder. Isn't it? I'm a bit confused. In script i'm trying to understand, the original string is:
`((($(stat -c '0%#a' "$FILE_PATH") & $(stat -c '0%#a' "${FILE_PATH%/*}") & 0007) == 0)) || echo 'Attention! The $(FILE_PATH%%*/) is accessible for everybody'`

But as I understand, the resulted `0` means that no `others` can access folder or file.

Comment: Right, the short-circuiting `||` executes only if the thing on the left-hand side was false, so the echo runs only if `== 0` wasn't true. It _is_ true in your case, so the warning won't print.

Comment: Finally, I got it!
It would echo'ed if it were `&&`.

Comment: Just came back to say that operator precedence is important. & has higher precedence then | so in this case the parentheses are required.

Comment: It doesn't matter with three `&`s, because commutative, but right, it does matter when you're mixing `&`s and `|`s.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i used your advise to compose my variant of permissions checking with `&` and `|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `stat -c '0%#a' "$FILE_PATH"` gets the permissions of your file itself, with a leading 0 to ensure that they're interpreted in octal.
- `stat -c '0%#a' "${FILE_PATH%/*}"` gets the permission of the directory that contains that file.
- ORing together the above results us tells us which permissions *either* of the above have, whereas ANDing them tells us which permissions *both* have. The above logic does a bitwise AND, but it would be safer / more secure if it did a bitwise OR.
- `0007` looks only at "other" permissions: Whether users who are neither the owner nor in the group have any read, write or execute. ANDing with this set tells us if the result of the above operation includes any permissions applicable to users who neither own or share a group with the file or directory.

**As currently written**, by ANDing together the directory and file permissions, and then ANDing that with `0007`, we check if *both* the file and directory are readable, writable, or executable by users who don't have any ownership interest; but we miss cases where the directory is readable/writable/executable but not the file, or the file but not the directory.

**If this were fixed**, by ORing together the file and directory permissions and then ANDing the result with `0007`, the net effect is to check whether the file or its containing directory can be read, written, or executed (for the directory, cd'd into) by users who neither own nor are in the group that owns that filesystem object.